# jQuery Error when selecting element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting an error when attempting to use the selected element using it's ID. Below is the function, the error occures when attempting to use `this` in place of `document.GetElementById()`.

```
(function($) {

        $.fn.multimap = function( options ) {



            // This is the easiest way to have default options.
            var settings = $.extend({
                // These are the defaults.
                locations: [
                    ['Address Title', 'Add Address Here', {lat: 53.008756, lng: -2.181422}]
                ],
                iconSize: { width: 70, height: 70 },
                zoom: 10,
                mapType: 'ROADMAP'

            }, options );

            var map;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            // Override handles
            var i_iconSize = settings.iconSize;
            if (settings.iconSize.constructor !== Object) { 
                i_iconSize = { width: settings.iconSize, height: settings.iconSize };
            }


            function initialize() {
                var lat = parseFloat(settings.locations[0][2]['lat']);
                var lng = parseFloat(settings.locations[0][2]['lng']);
                var i_mapType;

                switch(settings.mapType) {
                    case "ROADMAP":
                        i_mapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
                        break;
                    case "SATELLITE":
                        i_mapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;
                        break;
                    case "HYBRID":
                        i_mapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;
                        break;
                    case "TERRAIN":
                        i_mapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;
                        break;
                }

                map = new google.maps.Map(
                this, {
                    // Initial center point, changes ones the markers are added though
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),

                    // This doesn't seme to work, seems to just scale to fit all markers in at the moment
                    zoom: settings.zoom,

                    // Change the map type, not sure what the others are called
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });

                for (i = 0; i < (settings.locations).length; i++) {
                    createMarker(settings.locations, i);
                }
            }
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

This is the call to the function:

```
$("#map_canvas").multimap({ });
```

Comment: I did not see in your code, where you call `document.getElementById();` (small g), and did not see what called and where is function `getComputedStyle`.

Comment: the scope of `this` does not extend to the initialize function. either pass `this` to the function, or save a reference to `this` when you enter the multimap function, e.g. `var obj = this;` and then work with `obj`.

Comment: @mpf82 I had to add `var obj = this[0];` as for some reason there was 2 objects in that object.

Comment: Sounds like your id `map_canvas` is not unique throughout your HTML.

Comment: @mpf82 just viewed source and searched for the ID and the only matches is the ID in the div and then the selector call in the javascript.